# How do I add data from a dropped item to a form using YUI and Knockout JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, yui

I have a list, which is populated with JSON-data, using Knockout JS.

Using YUI delegates, each of the list elements are draggable, with several drop targets (using YUI `dd-drop-plugin`).

When I drop a list item on one of the drop targets, I want an existing form to populate with data from the dropped item’s data (even data not presented in the list, but which is in the data model). If nothing is dropped, I still want the user to be able to edit the form, and submit it.

My original view is:

```
 <ol class="timeline" data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <li>  
        <p data-bind="text: Title"></p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Which is populated by:

```
$.getJSON(timelineURL, function(data) {
        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("preleads"));
    });
```

Then I have the YUI dd:

```
YUI().use('dd-delegate', 'dd-drag','dd-drop-plugin', 'dd-proxy', function(Y) {

    // Make all the .timeline items draggable
    var draggables = new Y.DD.Delegate({
        container: ".timeline",
        nodes: "li"
    });

    // ... some setting up of the proxy elements, etc.

    var dropNew = Y.one("#addStoryForm").plug(Y.Plugin.Drop);
    dropNew.drop.on("drop:hit", function(e){

        // The bit I'm missing

    });

});
```

Which should populate a form with the data from the dropped element:

```
<form data-bind="with: droppedItem">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Title" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: SomethingElse" />
    <button type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use YUI, but I googled a bit. I'm guessing it should be something like this:

```
dropNew.drop.on("drop:hit", function(e){
    var element = e.drag, // YUI bit I'm unsure about
        data = ko.dataFor(element);
    droppedItem(data);
});
```

I'm fairly sure that when you do it like this, any changes you make in the form are immediatly reflected in the list. If you do not want this, you have to do a bit more work:

```
data = ko.toJS(ko.dataFor(element));
droppedItem().Title(data.Title);
droppedItem().SomethingElse(data.SomethingElse);
```